# Flutter Hero with custom AnimationController or entirely custom overlay

Tags: flutter, overlay, hero

Is it possible to implement a Hero Animation in flutter but instead of being controlled by Navigator, be controlled by a custom AnimationController.

This is for a use case needs to go inside another element rather than a new screen as is the case with Navigator.

Alternatively, is it possible to directly inject a widget into an overlay that is fixed permanently elsewhere on the screen preserving the state, logic and controllers of where it was initially declared.

Imagine I have content that changes on a page based on a certain user interaction but still should animate a transition of a sliver app bar as if a new screen has entered when it had not.

In laymen's terms, I want to declare a widget wherever I happen to declare it but not actually render there. IT should render instead in a targeted location but still maintain any state or controllers it obtained or inherited from the position in which it was actually declare.

Comment: "Imagine I have content that changes on a page based on a certain user interaction but still should animate a transition of a sliver app bar as if a new screen has entered when it had not" - cannot you use a nested `Navigator` which would change to content?

Comment: No not in this scenario as the content of the new sliver app bar would not be pushed on top of the existing page but on the content on the page.  I believe I am looking for a way to either replicate the function of a hero animation with a custom animation controller or push content directly into an overlay by target. I can't find a any significant documentation outlining quite how to do that.

Comment: i am list to be honest, which widget you want to act as `Hero` actually?

Comment: It's more about being able to create a widget in one place but have it render above. This is how a hero works as far as I understand. It places the content in an overlay during the Navigator transition, performs a size transition between the old widget and the new widget using the Route context animation and secondary animation. Navigator has limitations and is not a fit for this particular situation. The ability to render content however in a different location from where it is declared is how a hero works and it is that element of it that I want to recreate.

Comment: @pskink I think I can achieve what I want with a stateful widget that accepts all content that should fit into a specific container via a function. IT should also be given a local context so it can look up the animation controller in reference to where it came from. I'm sorry if my methods seem alien to you but standard Navigator does not provide a way of carrying this out and having dissected the code completely it appears to work like this to some extent behind the scenes. Therefore creating a version of it to support this use case seems logical to me.

Comment: is your question anyhow related to "accordion list" you mention in your other question from the last days? if so, do you have problems with moving the items to the bottom nav bar?

Comment: Partly, that is one scenario where this may be useful, but there are other scenarios where the content of a pushed route needs to go in an entirely different place than it's navigation bars and certain sub widgets of the main widget that has pushed. I have found that trying to get existing widgets to perform these behaviours is ultimately more complex than building a custom implementation to replace things like navigator that does support what I'm trying to achieve.  Much of this was possible using state notifier and riverbed but not all, which is where I think stateful can come in to plat.